# Poisson Process. Expected time of three fishermen catching at least three fish.

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

Three fishermen are fishing, we model the fishing as a Poisson Process of rate $2.5$ fish/hour. The fishermen leave only when each of them them has caught at least 3 fish, we call this leaving time $T$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[T]$.

My attempt:

I started out calculating the distribution $F_T$:

$F_T(t)=\mathbb{P}(X_1(t)\ge 3, X_2(t)\ge 3, X_3(t)\ge 3)=(\mathbb{P}(X_1(t)\ge 3))^3,$
where I have assumed independence of the Poisson processes corresponding to each fisherman $X_i$. Then I integrate $(1-F_T)$ to get the expectation.

Question: Is my reasoning correct? The numerical calculation yields an expected time of 3.56 hours. Also, is there any easier way to do this using arrival waiting or interarrival times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How appropriate, modeling fishing as a Poisson Process.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There even are many papers titled "Fishing in Poisson streams", e.g. [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2836)

Answer (score 1):

I think you started off OK in finding $F_T(t)$. To find $E(T)$, you need to differentiate $F_T(t)$ to get $f_T(t)$ and use that to obtain $E(T)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_T(t) &=& F_T^{'}(t) \\
&=& \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( 1-e^{-\lambda t} - \lambda te^{-\lambda t} - \dfrac{(\lambda t)^2}{2}e^{-\lambda t} \right)^3 \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{2} \lambda^3 t^2 e^{-\lambda t}  \left( 1-e^{-\lambda t} - \lambda te^{-\lambda t} - \dfrac{(\lambda t)^2}{2}e^{-\lambda t} \right)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

$$\\$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(T) &=& \int_{t=0}^{\infty}{tf_T(t)\;dt} \\
&=& \int_{t=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{3}{2} \lambda^3 t^3 e^{-\lambda t}  \left( 1-e^{-\lambda t} - \lambda te^{-\lambda t} - \dfrac{(\lambda t)^2}{2}e^{-\lambda t} \right)^2\;dt} \\
&=& \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3888\lambda} e^{-3\lambda t}\left[ -5832 e^{2\lambda t} (\lambda^3t^3 + 3\lambda^2t^2 + 6\lambda t + 6) + 729e^{\lambda t} (4\lambda^5t^5 + 18\lambda^4t^4 + 44\lambda^3t^3 + 66\lambda^2t^2 + 66\lambda t + 33) -2(243\lambda^7t^7 + 1539\lambda^6t^6 + 5022\lambda^5t^5 + 10314\lambda^4t^4 + 14724\lambda^3t^3 + 14724\lambda^2t^2 + 9816\lambda t + 3272) \right] \bigg]_0^{\infty} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(using WolframAlpha)} \\
&=& \dfrac{-1}{3888\lambda} \left( -5832\times 6 + 729 \times 33 - 2\times 3272 \right) \\
&=& \dfrac{17579}{9720} \\
&\approx& 1.81 \text{ hours}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}